# What is the map data structure in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, dictionary, std

What is the data structure used for following line of code in C++?

```
map <char, int> dict;
```

Is it a hash table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` uses hashing to store its objects.

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not impose any specific implementation on `std::map`. It only gives the required operations and their complexity. Those factors lead to the actual implementation choice which is usually a [Red-black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

The chapter listing the requirements for `std::map` is  `23.2.4 Associative Containers` in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

It is *usually* implemented with a self-balancing BST. Implementation is actually compiler specific.

```
std::map<char, int> dict;
```

A `char` is the key while an `int` is the corresponding value.

Comment: I don't think there is any requirement for it to be Red-Black tree implementation.  It could be anything under the hood if the semantics are followed.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Red-Black Tree to organize keys in order.

That's why you can iterate it in ascending order, and the key object has to have operator< overloaded.