# How is the keys searched in a STL map?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, stl

How are keys stored and searched in a STL `std::map`? What is the data structure used to store keys (or values also) in map and what algorithm is used to search the keys in `std::map`?

Comment: [What is the map data structure in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12207634)

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/):

> Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees.

By default `less<T>` is used to compare keys, but you can specify your custom compare function for that as template parameter.